# How to change boxplot axis name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, echarts

now I hava drawed a boxplot, but the axis name is not my expected , I want the axis name is like "1A, 5B, 20C, 60D, 500F", see the picture.

[boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w9ZU.png)

environments:
echarts: v5.4

the source code is below:

```js
option = {
  title: [
    {
      text: 'Michelson-Morley Experiment',
      left: 'center'
    },
    {
      text: 'upper: Q3 + 1.5 * IQR \nlower: Q1 - 1.5 * IQR',
      borderColor: '#999',
      borderWidth: 1,
      textStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontSize: 14,
        lineHeight: 20
      },
      left: '10%',
      top: '90%'
    }
  ],
  dataset: [
    {
      // prettier-ignore
      source: [
                [850, 740, 900, 1070, 930, 850, 950, 980, 980, 880, 1000, 980, 930, 650, 760, 810, 1000, 1000, 960, 960],
                [960, 940, 960, 940, 880, 800, 850, 880, 900, 840, 830, 790, 810, 880, 880, 830, 800, 790, 760, 800],
                [880, 880, 880, 860, 720, 720, 620, 860, 970, 950, 880, 910, 850, 870, 840, 840, 850, 840, 840, 840],
                [890, 810, 810, 820, 800, 770, 760, 740, 750, 760, 910, 920, 890, 860, 880, 720, 840, 850, 850, 780],
                [890, 840, 780, 810, 760, 810, 790, 810, 820, 850, 870, 870, 810, 740, 810, 940, 950, 800, 810, 870]
            ]
    },
    {
      transform: {
        type: 'boxplot',
        config: { itemNameFormatter: function(params) {
          return params.value + 'A' 
        }},
      }
    },
    {
      fromDatasetIndex: 1,
      fromTransformResult: 1
    }
  ],
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'shadow'
    }
  },
  grid: {
    left: '10%',
    right: '10%',
    bottom: '15%'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: true,
    nameGap: 30,
    splitArea: {
      show: false
    },
    splitLine: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    name: 'km/s minus 299,000',
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'boxplot',
      type: 'boxplot',
      datasetIndex: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'outlier',
      type: 'scatter',
      datasetIndex: 2
    }
  ]
};
```

I want the axis name is like "1A, 5B, 20C, 60D, 500F", just like the above picture.

Do you have any idea how can this be done?

Thanks ^_^

Comment: sorry, the above picture may be not visual , see this : https://gitee.com/Zcb991/upload_images/blob/master/20230118/111.png

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this if we take your code in its current state is to test `params.value` using a **`switch` statement**:

```js
let option = {
  title: [
    {
      text: 'Michelson-Morley Experiment',
      left: 'center'
    },
    {
      text: 'upper: Q3 + 1.5 * IQR \nlower: Q1 - 1.5 * IQR',
      borderColor: '#999',
      borderWidth: 1,
      textStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontSize: 14,
        lineHeight: 20
      },
      left: '10%',
      top: '90%'
    }
  ],
  dataset: [
    {
      // prettier-ignore
      source: [
        [850, 740, 900, 1070, 930, 850, 950, 980, 980, 880, 1000, 980, 930, 650, 760, 810, 1000, 1000, 960, 960],
        [960, 940, 960, 940, 880, 800, 850, 880, 900, 840, 830, 790, 810, 880, 880, 830, 800, 790, 760, 800],
        [880, 880, 880, 860, 720, 720, 620, 860, 970, 950, 880, 910, 850, 870, 840, 840, 850, 840, 840, 840],
        [890, 810, 810, 820, 800, 770, 760, 740, 750, 760, 910, 920, 890, 860, 880, 720, 840, 850, 850, 780],
        [890, 840, 780, 810, 760, 810, 790, 810, 820, 850, 870, 870, 810, 740, 810, 940, 950, 800, 810, 870]
      ]
    },
    {
      transform: {
        type: 'boxplot',
        config: {
          // ========================= HERE =========================
          itemNameFormatter: params => {
            switch (params.value) {
              case 0:
                return '1A';
              case 1:
                return '5B';
              case 2:
                return '20C';
              case 3:
                return '60D';
              case 4:
                return '500F';
            }
          }
          // ==================================================
        }
      }
    },
    {
      fromDatasetIndex: 1,
      fromTransformResult: 1
    }
  ],
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'shadow'
    }
  },
  grid: {
    left: '10%',
    right: '10%',
    bottom: '15%'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: true,
    nameGap: 30,
    splitArea: {
      show: false
    },
    splitLine: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    name: 'km/s minus 299,000',
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'boxplot',
      type: 'boxplot',
      datasetIndex: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'outlier',
      type: 'scatter',
      datasetIndex: 2
    }
  ]
};

let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```